# How can I sequentially test 10+continuous covariates (individual questions in an inventory) in my model (repeated measures)

Tags: regression, mixed-model

Basically I have data from two inventories (which have 7-10 questions on a likert scale). They  were both administered at 4 different times. I am using GALMj package in jamovi to run a mixed model because I have some other categorical factors to consider.

They cover overlapping (but not identical constructs). I am trying figure out how I can sequentially add individual combinations of questions from Inventory A, to see which attributes explain the majority of variance in Inventory B.

Is there a way to automate (i.e. sequentially add or subtract each covariate until you find the best fit?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for some sort of step-wise selection method in the mixed model. GAMLj does not have this feature because in the mixed model it is not (yet) recommended to use automated predictors selection methods. The main reason is the following: When you change the structure of the fixed effects (removing or adding IV's),  the definition of the random effects structure should be adjusted accordingly. That requires a thoughtful choice by the analyst.

Nonetheless, you can explore the plausibility of your model by adding or removing variables and terms in the model, always defining fixed effects and random effects accordingly to the research design.